# DELETE https://localhost:44382/Admin/stocks 404 spread.js:25

Tags: asp.net, api, axios, http-status-code-404, http-delete

Im stuck, i tried everything, cant find it please help me...

Console: DELETE https://localhost:44382/Admin/stocks 404 spread.js:25

code:

```
deleteStock(id, index) {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.delete('/Admin/stocks' + id)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.selectedProduct.stock.splice(index, 1);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        },
```